# Following error is coming when the button is clicked to hit an api

Tags: android

I have made a sign up activity in android. 
On clicking the button, I am hitting an api with url:
task.execute("http://10.0.2.2:8080/TestWebService_war_exploded/hello");

I have used 127.0.0.1 instead of 10.0.0.2 also
but that also doesn't work.

I am getting the following errors in log once I click the button

> W/System.err: java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT
>   communication to 10.0.2.2 not permitted by network security policy
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:146)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>           at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
>           at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
>           at com.example.android.complaintbox_ritesltd.activity_SignUp$DownloadWebPageTask.doInBackground(activity_SignUp.java:70)
>           at com.example.android.complaintbox_ritesltd.activity_SignUp$DownloadWebPageTask.doInBackground(activity_SignUp.java:60)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

code is given as:

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // we use the OkHttp library from https://github.com/square/okhttp
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        try{
            Request request =
                    new Request.Builder()
                            .url(urls[0])
                            .build();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                return response.body().string();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return "Download failed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textView.setText(result);
    }
}

// Triggered via a button in your layout
public void onClick(View view) {


    DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    task.execute("http://10.0.2.2:8080/TestWebService_war_exploded/hello");

}
```

}

Already did all the changes in manifest ..

I am trying to run it on emulator..

Comment: Have you declare permission INTERNET in ur AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: can you provide complete code..i mean how you are making API request

Comment: yup.. edited in the question

Comment: Simple add _android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"_ in manifest file within _<application>_ tag.

Comment: @Piyush tried but then warning is displayed for api 23 or higher

Comment: What is your minimum and target version?

Comment: I changed both to 28 .. Now the warning is removed.. but error remains same..

Comment: also, other urls are working fine.. only this url is generating problems

Comment: Is it local host url or live url?

Comment: I tried changing to http://127.0.0.1/.... also, but that is not helping

Comment: local url @piyush

Comment: live urls are working fine

Comment: If it is local url then it will not work in real device. You have to run it in emulator only.

Comment: yes .. I am running this in emulator only

Comment: Emulator has pie version ???

Comment: yes.. I downloaded the emulator yesterday only

Comment: Check [this](https://androidfreetutorial.wordpress.com/2019/03/04/android-connection-issue-cleartext-communication-not-permitted-by-network-security-policy/)

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

In your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...
</application>
</manifest>
```

also add internet permission in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Attribute usesCleartextTraffic is only used in API level 23 and higher (current min is 15) less... (Ctrl+F1)

Comment: This warning is displayed

Comment: take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/9060917

Comment: I already tried it

Comment: same warning is displayed

Comment: set target sandbox version to 1

Comment: tried that as well